# What kind of of object does this function return?

Tags: c++, declaration, return-type

Imagine that you have a situation like this:

```
class  className{
...
}

className func(){
    className cl;
    ...
    return cl;     
}

int main(){
    ...
    func();
}
```

What does the function `func()` return when you call it in the body of the program? A temporary copy of the object `cl`? 
I don't understand this, since in the body of the function `func()` you can get the address  `&cl`, but you get an error if you try to call `&(func())` inside the function `main()`.

Comment: The ways of compiler optimization are infinite. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: One thing that might be useful in figuring out these types of things is to define the constructor and copy constructor of `className` to "`cout`" something. Add a few "`cout`'s" in and out of the function and you can clearly see where cl is getting constructed and copied to return to main.

Comment: `className cx = foo();` would probably be easier to understand. And what you're trying with `&(func())` make no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function you are dealing with a so-called lvalue shortly speaking with an object which address is known because the object is defined explicitly. 
The return value of the function is a temporary object (it is a so-called rvalue). Its address is not known. We do not know 
where the compiler defined this object. So we may not apply operator & to a temporary object.

Another similar example

```
struct A
{
   int x;
};

A f() { return A(); }

int main()
{
   f().x = 10;  // here the compiler will issue an error
}
```

This code shall not be compiled though for example MS VC++ 2010 will compile it due to either a bug or its language extension.:)

Comment: thank you. I didn't know about lvalues and rvalues. Now I understood the philosophy of this stuff.